# re-sizing image in c# doesn't work

Tags: c#, bitmap

I am trying to resize image to `width=100` `height=100`

```
public ActionResult RegisterUser(userAuthModel user, HttpPostedFileBase userimage)
{
    if (userimage.ContentLength > 0 && userimage != null)
    {
        string fname = userimage.FileName;
        var path = Server.MapPath("~/Images/User_DP/" + userimage.FileName);
        var image_100 = new System.Drawing.Bitmap(userimage, new Size(100, 100));
        userimage.SaveAs(path);

    }
    .
    .
    .
    .
    .
}
```

Here I am using bitmap approach to resize imgae to some specific width and height.

But this shows me error in line-

```
var image_100 = new System.Drawing.Bitmap(userimage, new Size(100, 100));
```

of invalid arguments. How Do Ii resize image with using bitmap?

Comment: So invalid arguments means that either `userImage` or `new Size(100, 100)` is an invalid argument for that method. If you look at the [MSDN Page for Bitmap type](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.bitmap.bitmap(v=vs.110).aspx) you can see that the constructor does not accept `HttpPostedFileBase` as an argument.

Answer (score 0):

you have to use mentioned method it may help you

```
private static BitmapFrame CreateResizedImage(ImageSource source, int width, int height, int margin)
{

    var rect = new Rect(margin, margin, width - margin * 2, height - margin * 2);

    var group = new DrawingGroup();
    RenderOptions.SetBitmapScalingMode(group, BitmapScalingMode.HighQuality);
    group.Children.Add(new ImageDrawing(source, rect));

    var drawingVisual = new DrawingVisual();
    using (var drawingContext = drawingVisual.RenderOpen())
        drawingContext.DrawDrawing(group);

    var resizedImage = new RenderTargetBitmap(
        width, height,         // Resized dimensions
        96, 96,                // Default DPI values
        PixelFormats.Default); // Default pixel format
    resizedImage.Render(drawingVisual);

    return BitmapFrame.Create(resizedImage);
}
```

Comment: Doing his homework for him doesn't help him become better at solving these problems on his own.

Answer (score 0):

The `System.Drawing.Bitmap` class asks for two parameters in the constructor your are using:

```
System.Drawing.Image
System.Drawing.Size
```

In your code, you are passing the size correctly, but not the image. `HttpPostedFileBase` does not extend the Image class.

You will need to change that part of your code. If you are using the `HttpPostedFileBase` as a stream, then keep in mind that `System.Drawing.Bitmap` has no constructor asking for a `Stream` and a `Size`.

References:

[System.Drawing.Image](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0wh0045z%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

[System.Web.HttpPostedFileBase](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httppostedfilebase%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)